# Kohana sample CRUD application

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, crud

I'm completely new to this framework and I'm trying to find some sample CRUD application to get started with Kohana 3.

There is a tutorial and information in the unofficial Kohana 3 Wiki (http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php), but even there, there are some aspects that are not covered (the model, validation, etc).

Comment: @Greelmo the question is: Is there a sample crud application for Kohana? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find the example code hosted on shadowhand's [github repo](http://github.com/shadowhand/wingsc) useful. It provides the code for a complete website and there are other projects for Kohana3 hosted on github that you should be able to locate without too much trouble that you might find useful.